# Wordpress website user/member info

Tags: php, wordpress, web

I'm starting a website for my small business and am going to use WordPress. I have a few questions.

1. I have seen a lot of info on customizing user login/registration pages with plugins but cannot find much on actually making the pages to begin with. Can you make a login/registration page with just stock standard WordPress setting/options, or do you need a plugin?
2. I want my customers to be able to sign up to the website (for free), mainly so i have an email list of all my clients and can email them about deals, etc. Where does WordPress save my customers' usernames and emails?
3. Are there any other plugins you can suggest to make a small ecommerce site go smoothly (I already know about woocommerce)?

Answer (score 0):

**Customizing the login:**
Manually it is generally done by adding custom login css from your themes functions.php.

**Registering Users:**
In the settings you can select to allow anyone to register.
I believe Woocommerce has options to force customers to register.

Your subscribers/customers emails and usernames are saved to the users table in the wordpress database and will be displayed on via the user menu in the admin panel.